# if condition causes exception. How to correct?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

i have following code:

```
For i = 0 To dt3.Rows.Count - 1

            If dt3.Rows(i).Item("tablename") <> oldtablename Then

                oldtablename = dt3.Rows(i).Item("tablename")

                *****SOME CODE HERE******

            Else

                *****SOME CODE HERE******
            End If


            If i = dt3.Rows.Count-1 Or oldtablename <> dt3.Rows(i + 1).Item("tablename") Then
                ''time to build up the query and execute it...
                query = query1 & query2 
                dtCDV = executequery(query)

            End If

        Next
```

The last IF causes a exception because dt3.rows(i+1)... is larger than the number of rows if it reaches the last row. I need this last if condition to be executed in 2 cases:

1) if we are on the last iteration of the for loop
2) if oldtablename is different than the variable contained in the next row (if next row exists...)

how can this be written properly?

Thanks

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` and fix the errors, it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following solution, using [`OrElse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/orelse-operator) instead of `Or` on the 
 last `if` condition:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dt3.Rows.Count - 1

    If dt3.Rows(i)("tablename") <> oldtablename Then
        oldtablename = dt3.Rows(i)("tablename")

        'some code here
    Else

        'some code here
    End If

     If i = dt3.Rows.Count-1 OrElse oldtablename <> dt3.Rows(i + 1)("tablename") Then

         'time to build up the query and execute it...
         query = query1 & query2 
         dtCDV = executequery(query)
     End If
 Next
```

In this case the right part (`oldtablename <> dt3.Rows(i + 1)("tablename")`) of the condition is only evaluated if the left part (`i = dt3.Rows.Count-1`) of the condition is `False`.